# Filter web parts in SharePoint 2013 STANDARD

Tags: web-part, 2013

I'm not able to find **Filter** web part category along with the other categories as i try to add the **Date Filter** web part to my **Publishing Site** that has **Empty Web Part Page** as it's layout. Is it that the **Standard** version of SharePoint 2013 doesn't provide Filter web parts? Or am I missing some feature? Or are such kind of web parts specific to certain site types/page layouts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I "assume" Filter web parts are part of SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Edition, as this was true in SP 2007 and I believe in SP 2010. However I did not find any useful information in the web. I do understand if this Kind of Basic web part is missing from SharePoint Foundation, but why it is not available in Standard Edition is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The Filter web parts in SharePoint 2013 are available if you activate the Enterprise Feature for your SiteCollection.

Comment: The "Enterprise Feature" is not part of SharePoint Standard though!